# How to use search filter when slug is used in URL path

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to add search and ordering filters to a page which is dynamically created with a `<slug:slug>`. The issue is that as soon as I add my ordering filter I get:

> Reverse for 'quiz-results-filtered' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['tests\/results\/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\/$']

If I am reading this correctly it is telling me that it can't determine the page when the filter is empty. Problem is that when I do not have the HTML ordering filter on the page it works just fine.

**Order_by button HTML:**

```
<!--Order By Button-->
        <form action="{% url 'quiz-results-filtered' %}" 
              class="small-form" 
              method="get">
            <input name="ordering"
                   type="hidden"
                   value="-end">
            <input class="btn btn-link"
                   type="submit"
                   value="Date: most recent">
        </form>
```

**URL:**

```
    path('tests/', include([
        path('results/<slug:slug>/', views.QuizMarkingFilteredList.as_view(), name='quiz-results-filtered'),
...
```

**Views.py** (although irrelevant some people made needlessly ask for this):

```
class QuizMarkingFilteredList(PermissionRequiredMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, QuizMarkerMixin, ListView):
    model = Sitting
    template_name = 'quiz/sitting_filtered_list.html'
    permission_required = ('quiz.view_sittings',)
    permission_denied_message = 'User does not have permissions to view quiz sittings.'

    def get_ordering(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ordering = self.request.GET.get('ordering', 'end')
        return ordering

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(QuizMarkingFilteredList, self).get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.filter(complete=True)
        queryset = queryset.filter(user__supervisor__exact=self.request.user)
        queryset = queryset.filter(quiz__url=self.kwargs['slug'])

        ordering = self.get_ordering()

        if ordering and isinstance(ordering, str):
            ordering = (ordering,)
            queryset = queryset.order_by(*ordering)
        return queryset
```

*This error **does not occur** when the HTML `Order_by` filter is removed from the page*.

I am sure it is pretty simple but I am not seeing it. Thoughts on why?

Thanks in advance! =D

Comment: Is the current path equal to the path that you want to go to but with your ordering (does it have the slug)?

Comment: Yes. For example the path which worked prior to adding the filter : `.../tests/results/BartendingQuiz`, where `BartendingQuiz` is the slug, simply throws this error when adding the `order_by` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is that you are trying to use the url "quiz-results-filtered" but it requires a slug keyword argument that you are not passing. You need to pass the argument to the url tag

```
{% url 'quiz-results-filtered' slug=slug %}
```

Removing the `action` attribute from the form tag will cause the form to submit to the current URL, you don't need it here as you are already on the correct path

```
<form class="small-form">
```

You also don't need to specify `method="get"` as it is the default

Comment: Would you mind explaining the cause of the error for future readers? I am assuming that it is redundantly trying to use this URL when the `action` attribute exists but what is going on here? EDIT: I see - I should be passing the `slug=slug` etc in the URL if that is what I really want to do. Rookie mistake. Thank you!

Comment: Added a bit of explanation